# Wordpress how to insert multiple CSS via custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-fields

I am struggling with `custom field` to insert page specific `CSS` or `JS` in Wordpress.

I was able to insert single CSS following the article.

> http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/embed-custom-css-in-your-single-posts-with-custom-fields/

Then I was wondering what if I want to insert multiple CSSs via a custom field.

I guess I have to do with Arrays and loops, right?

Can I just want put multiple CSSs in one field by separating with commas or something?

Example:
in the custom field section:

- field name: customCSS
- filed value: foo.css, bar.css, other.css ...

Could someone give me an idea how to do it?

Thank you.

My wordpress ver. is `3.8`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. basic PHP stuff...

I dont know if this is efficient, but I got what I want as a result.

I used comma(,) as a delimiter in the custom field.

```
if (is_page()) {
$uniqueCSS = get_post_meta($post->ID, uniqueCSS ,true);
$uniqueCSSArr = explode(',', $uniqueCSS);
if($uniqueCSSArr) {
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($uniqueCSSArr); $i++ ) {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/'. $uniqueCSSArr[$i] .'"/>';
        echo "\n";
    }
}
}
```

Thank you